# Work around SQL Server maximum columns limit 1024 and 8kb record size

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a table with 1000 columns. Most of the columns are `nvarchar` type. Table is created, but with a warning

> *Warning: The table "Test" has been created, but its maximum row size
>   exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to this
>   table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit.*

Most of the columns of the table already have data in it (i.e. 99% of columns have data).
When I am trying to update any column after the 310th (where as all starting 309 columns having some value) it gives error:

> *Cannot create a row of size 8061 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060.*

I am inserting this data to all starting 308 columns

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit."

When I am using `ntext` data type then it is allowing me to update about 450 columns but beyond of that `ntext` is also not allowing me. I have to update at least 700 columns. Which SQL Server is not allowing to do that. I have the scenario that I cannot move some columns of table to another table.

Actually I am working for an existing window application. It's a very large windows application.

Actually the table in which I am trying to insert up to 700 nvarchar columns data is created dynamically at runtime.
Only in some cases it requires to insert 400-600 columns. But generally it need 100 -200 columns which i am able to process easily.

The problem is that I cannot split this table in multiple tables. Because a lots of tables created with this structures and names of tables are maintained in another table i.e. there are more than 100 tables with this structure and they are being created dynamically. For creating the table and manipulating its data 4-5 languages(C#, Java..) are being used and WCF, Windows Service and Webservices also Involves.

So I don't think that it would be easy manipulate the table and its data after splitting the table. If I split the table then it would require lots of structural changes.

So please suggest me that what would be the best way to solve this issue.

I have also tried to use **Sparse Column** like:

```
Create table ABCD(Id int, Name varchar(100) Sparse, Age int);
```

I have also thought about **ColumnStoreIndex** but my purpose is not solved.

Sparse column allow me to create 3000 columns for a table but it also restrict me on page size.

Is any way to achieve it using some temporary table or by using any other type of SQL server object?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why in heck would you need 1000 columns?

Comment: If you need 1000 columns in a sql table, I would seriously reconsider your design.

Comment: There are limits for each row in SQL server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx gives details

Comment: You can't do this anyway. You will **have** to reconsider the design. The in row data can't exceed 8060 bytes and the pointers for off row storage add up to longer than that well before 700 columns.

Comment: We aren't going to give you a sql server patch anyway, so you have to change your data model, because it is just not possible

Comment: If you need a table with 1000 columns, use a flat file. What do you need a RDBMS for?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  More recent versions allow excess sizes strings to spill over onto other data pages.  You can force this in older versions by making all the character strings `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Won't help. Ordinary `varchar` can be stored off row too. It still needs to store a pointer in row to the data. No way of getting 700 `varchar` columns with data longer than the pointer as the size of the pointers itself exceeds the row limit as shown in the question.

Comment: ...Do you have a 1000" monitor to view your 1000 columns on ^_^

Comment: @SWeko easy, data mining/scientific modeling can often use that many columns.

Comment: Use nvarchar(MAX) as type

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**SQL Server Maximum Columns Limit**

Bytes per short string column   **8,000**

Bytes per GROUP BY, ORDER BY     **8,060**

Bytes per row   **8,060**

Columns per index key   **16**

Columns per foreign key **16**

Columns per primary key **16**

Columns per nonwide table   **1,024**

Columns per wide table  **30,000**

Columns per SELECT statement    **4,096**

Columns per INSERT statement    **4096**

Columns per UPDATE statement (Wide Tables)  **4096**

When you combine **varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant,** or CLR user-defined type columns that exceed **8,060** bytes per row, consider the following:

Surpassing the 8,060-byte row-size limit might affect performance because SQL Server still maintains a limit of 8 KB per page. When a combination of varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, or CLR user-defined type columns exceeds this limit, the SQL Server Database Engine moves the record column with the largest width to another page in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit, while maintaining a 24-byte pointer on the original page. Moving large records to another page occurs dynamically as records are lengthened based on update operations. Update operations that shorten records may cause records to be moved back to the original page in the IN_ROW_DATA allocation unit. Also, querying and performing other select operations, such as sorts or joins on large records that contain row-overflow data slows processing time, because these records are processed synchronously instead of asynchronously.

Therefore, when you design a table with multiple varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, or CLR user-defined type columns, consider the percentage of rows that are likely to flow over and the frequency with which this overflow data is likely to be queried. If there are likely to be frequent queries on many rows of row-overflow data, consider normalizing the table so that some columns are moved to another table. This can then be queried in an asynchronous JOIN operation.

- The length of individual columns must still fall within the limit of
  8,000 bytes for varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, and CLR
  user-defined type columns. Only their combined lengths can exceed the
  8,060-byte row limit of a table.
- The sum of other data type columns, including char and nchar data,
  must fall within the 8,060-byte row limit. Large object data is also
  exempt from the 8,060-byte row limit.
- The index key of a clustered index cannot contain varchar columns
  that have existing data in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit. If
  a clustered index is created on a varchar column and the existing
  data is in the IN_ROW_DATA allocation unit, subsequent insert or
  update actions on the column that would push the data off-row will
  fail. For more information about allocation units, see Table and
  Index Organization.
- You can include columns that contain row-overflow data as key or
  nonkey columns of a nonclustered index.
- The record-size limit for tables that use sparse columns is 8,018
  bytes. When the converted data plus existing record data exceeds
  8,018 bytes, MSSQLSERVER ERROR 576 is returned. When columns are
  converted between sparse and nonsparse types, Database Engine keeps a
  copy of the current record data. This temporarily doubles the storage
  that is required for the record. .
- To obtain information about tables or indexes that might contain
  row-overflow data, use the sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats dynamic
  management function.

**Creating table with n number of columns and datatype Nvarchar**

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[CreateMaxColTable_Nvarchar500]
(@TableName nvarchar(100),@NumofCols int)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @j VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @len int
SELECT @i=1
SELECT @MAX=@NumofCols
SET @SQL='CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '('

WHILE @i<=@MAX

BEGIN
select @j= cast(@i as varchar)
SELECT @SQL= @SQL+'X'+@j  +' NVARCHAR(500) , '
SET @i = @i + 1
END
select @len=len(@SQL)

select  @SQL = substring(@SQL,0,@len-1)


SELECT @SQL= @SQL+ ' )'

exec (@SQL)

END
```

For more information you can visit these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981%28SQL.105%29.aspx?PHPSESSID=tn8k5p1s508cop8gr43e1f34d2

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

But please could you tell the scenario why do you need a table with so much columns?
I think you should consider about the re-design of the database.

Comment: Actually I am facing this issue for an existing application.It is having 10 databases. About 5-6 databases using such type of table. The table is created dynamically at run time and number of the columns for the table depends upon the data being processed at that time. I have surf the internet and found that I can not create any table with so many columns But I need it. So is any alternative solution to do that?

Comment: I have also used text/ntext which uses 16 bytes  pointer. Whereas varchar/nvarchar uses 24bytes pointer. But my purpose is not solved.

Answer (score 13):

This simply isn't possible. See [Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a record](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-record.aspx)

Assuming your table is something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(
    col_1 varchar(8000) NULL,
    col_2 varchar(8000) NULL,
    /*....*/
    col_999 varchar(8000) NULL,
    col_1000 varchar(8000) NULL
)
```

Then even a row with all `NULL` values will use the following storage.

- 1 byte status bits A
- 1 byte status bits B
- 2 bytes column count offset
- 125 bytes `NULL_BITMAP` (1 `bit` per column for 1,000 columns)

So that is a guaranteed 129 bytes used up already (leaving 7,931).

If any of the columns have a value that is not either `NULL` or an empty string then you also need space for

- 2 bytes variable length column count  (leaving 7,929).
- Anywhere between 2 - 2000 bytes for the column offset array.
- The data itself.

The column offset array consumes 2 bytes per variable length column **except** if that column and all later columns are also zero length. So updating `col_1000` would force the entire 2000 bytes to be used whereas updating  `col_1` would just use 2 bytes.

So you could populate each column with 5 bytes of data and when taking into account the 2 bytes each in the column offset array that would add up to 7,000 bytes which is within the 7,929 remaining.

However the data you are storing is 102 bytes (51 `nvarchar` characters) so this can be stored off row with a 24 byte pointer to the actual data remaining in row.

```
FLOOR(7929/(24 + 2)) = 304
```

So the best case would be that you could store 304 columns of this length data and that is if you are updating from `col_1`, `col_2`, `...`. If `col_1000` contains data then the calculation is

```
FLOOR(5929/24) = 247
```

For `NTEXT` the calculation is similar except [it can use a 16 byte pointer](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1143500-391-1.aspx) which would allow you to squeeze data into a few extra columns

```
FLOOR(7929/(16 + 2)) = 440
```

The need to follow all these off row pointers for any `SELECT` against the table would likely be highly detrimental to performance.

### Script to test this

```
DROP TABLE T1

/* Create table with 1000 columns*/
DECLARE @CreateTableScript nvarchar(max) = 'CREATE TABLE T1('

SELECT @CreateTableScript += 'col_' + LTRIM(number) + ' VARCHAR(8000),'
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type='P' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
ORDER BY number

SELECT @CreateTableScript += ')'

EXEC(@CreateTableScript)

/* Insert single row with all NULL*/
INSERT INTO T1 DEFAULT VALUES


/*Updating first 304 cols succeed. Change to 305 and it fails*/
DECLARE @UpdateTableScript nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE T1 SET  '

SELECT @UpdateTableScript += 'col_' + LTRIM(number) + ' = REPLICATE(1,1000),'
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type='P' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 304
ORDER BY number

SET @UpdateTableScript = LEFT(@UpdateTableScript,LEN(@UpdateTableScript)-1)
EXEC(@UpdateTableScript)
```

Answer (score 10):

Having table with 1.000 columns tells you that there is something very wrong in database design.

I have inherited project in which one of the tables had more than 500 columns and after more than one year I am still unable to significantly reduce it, because I will have to rework 90% of the application.

So redesign your DB before it is too late.

Comment: Personally, I hate answers like this.  I have faced the problem on limitations on the number of columns in tables several times.  There are good reasons for it, especially when denormalizing data for analysis.  It is unfortunate that databases have such arcane limits.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Honestly I would be quite interested in why a table would never need 1000 columns. Can you shed any light why it would be needed? I can really think of a good one, would love to hear a counter example.

Comment: As I said, when you are denormalizing data for analysis, the number of columns is important.  A few years ago, the data used for the KDD competition ("knowledge discovery and data mining") was biogenetic data that had several hundred thousand columns.  Another example is document-term matrices used for text analysis.  And, just putting together historical data often results in hundreds or thousands of columns.

Comment: Indeed, we have reached the 1000 limit numerous times.

Comment: Another supporting reason to have a large number of columns on a table would be for a dynamic staging table where you really don't know how many fields you are going to need.  I have an SSIS package that reads a large CSV File, but the number of columns is unknown because even the 1-to-many data is held in there.  The best solution is a dynamic staging table which holds the data temporarily and then moved to the "real" relational tables.

Answer (score 2):

Max Columns per 'nonwide' table: 1,024
Max Columns per 'wide' table: 30,000

Although what is exactly the case you require this number per single table ?
It's highly recommended to partition your table vertically several times to get better performance and easier development.

Comment: That isn't going to help the OP. They have the desired 1,000 columns they just can't store the desired data in 700 of them in a single row.

Comment: There isn't a 700 limit. That is the number of columns they state they are trying to populate in the question. The limit for storing anything but very short `varchar` values is much less than that.

Comment: what is the meaning of wide and non wide table? please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

Creating table with n number of columns and datatype Nvarchar

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[CreateMaxColTable_Nvarchar500]
(@TableName nvarchar(100),@NumofCols int)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @j VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @len int
SELECT @i=1
SELECT @MAX=@NumofCols
SET @SQL='CREATE TABLE ' + @TableName + '('

WHILE @i<=@MAX

BEGIN
select @j= cast(@i as varchar)
SELECT @SQL= @SQL+'A'+@j  +' NVARCHAR(500) , '
SET @i = @i + 1
END
select @len=len(@SQL)

select  @SQL = substring(@SQL,0,@len-1)


SELECT @SQL= @SQL+ ' )'

exec (@SQL)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you really need to use nvarchar for all columns, nvarchar takes twice as bytes as varchar, so converting the columns to varchar where possible can reduce row data size and might help you overcome this error.

Answer (score -3):

We had application which captures 5000 fields for a loan application. All fields are dependent on a single primary key loanid. We could have split the table into multiples but the fields are also dynamic. The admin also has a feature to create more fields. So everything is dynamic. They only good thing was a one to one relationship between loanid and fields.

So, in the end we went with XML solution. The entire data is store in an xml document. Maximum flexibility but makes it diffifcult to query and report of.

Comment: Maximum flexibility is to use two tables. One that holds the loan. The other is a pivoted table that has one column to hold the "desired column name" / "desired XML node name", another column to hold the loan id, and another for the value. Otherwise switch to a no-sql solution like postgresql or mongodb.