# sql query - how to remove character limit on result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running the following query and it's hitting a character limit which I don't want.

```
SELECT
    '{"data":[', 
    (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + '{"{#DBNAME}":"' + [Name] + '"}' 
                   FROM master..sysdatabases 
                   ORDER BY [Name] 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) ,']}' 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Essentially we have more databases than the query wants to return which in turn breaks the json return.

The issue was not around the character limit imposed by the database but in the value returned from the query.  as already stated it was a matter of enforcing a larger limit than the default when returning the results.

Comment: Have you tried looking [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438056/is-there-a-way-around-the-8k-row-length-limit-in-sql-server)?

Comment: I had tried doing a cast but I can't figure out where to put it within the select.  at the very beginning doing `select cast(` I can't figure out where the `as nvarchar(max))` would go

Comment: I tried your query on a server containing over 90 database and it worked find. I could not see the complete string in the result grid but when I click on the result (it looks like a hyperlink), SSMS opens it in a new window and I see whole string which includes all my databases

Comment: take the returned result and paste here - `http://jsonprettyprint.com/` and see if it's a valid json.  I'm running off of 162 dbs and it fails because it's truncating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following by casting into ntext.
This worked for over 200 databases.
By the way http://jsonprettyprint.com/ seems to have a character limit itself

```
  SELECT
   '{"data":[', 
    (SELECT  convert(ntext,STUFF((SELECT ',' + '{"{#DBNAME}":"' + [Name] + '"}' 
                   FROM master..sysdatabases 
                   ORDER BY [Name] 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''))) ,']}' 
FOR XML PATH('')
```