# Handling data with 1000~ variables, preferably using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value, storing-data

Basically, I have tons of files with some data. each differ, some lack some variables(null) etc, classic stuff.

The part it gets somewhat interesting is that, since each file can have up to 1000 variables, and has at least 800~ values that is not null, I thought: "Hey I need 1000 columns". Another thing to mention is, they are integers, bools, text, everything. they differ by size, and type. Each variable is under 100 bytes, at all files, alth. they vary.

I found this question [Work around SQL Server maximum columns limit 1024 and 8kb record size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070932/sql-server-maximum-columns-limit)
Im unfamiliar with capacities of sql servers and table design, but the thing is: people who answered that question say that they should reconsider the design, but I cant do that. I however, can convert what I already have, as long as I still have that 1000 variables.

Im willing to use any sql server, but I dont know what suits my requirements best. If doing something else is better, please tell so.

**What I need to do with this data is, look, compare, and search within. I dont need the ability to modify these.** I thought of just using them as they are and keeping them as plain text files and reading from, that requires "seconds" of php runtime for viewing data out of "few" of these files and that is too much. Not even considering the fact that I need to check about 1000 or more of these files to do any search.

**So the question is, what is the fastest way of having 1000++ entities with 1000 variables each, and searching/comparing for any variable I wish within them, etc. ? and if its SQL, which SQL server functions best for this sort of stuff?**

Comment: What kind of searches will you be doing? Multiple exact field values known, get all matching documents? Freetext in some fields? Wildcards? Known value but search over multiple fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for best, I can give an answer (how I solved it), but cant say if it is the 'best' way (in your environment), I had the Problem to collect inventory data of many thousend PCs (no not NSA - kidding)

my soultion was:

One table per PC (File for you?)

Table File: 
    one row per file, PK FILE_ID

Table File_data
    one row per column in file, PK FILE_ID, ATTR_ID, ATTR_NAME, ATTR_VALUE, (ATTR_TYPE)

The Table File_data, was - somehow - big (>1e6 lines) but the DB handled that fast

HTH

**EDIT:**

I was pretty short in my anwser, lately; I want to put some additional information to *my* (and *still working*) solution:

the table 'per info source' has more than the two fields `PK, FILE_ID` ie. `ISOURCE, ITYPE`, where ISOURCE and ITYPE dscribe from where (I had many sources) and what basic Information type it is / was. This helps to get a structure into queries. I did not need to include data from 'switches' or 'monitors', when searching for USB divices (edit: to day probably: yes)

the attributes table had more fields, too. I mention here the both fileds: `ISOURCE, ITYPE`, yes, the same as above, but a slightly different meaning, the same idea behind

What you would have to put into these fields, depends definitely on your data.

I am sure, that if you take a closer look, what information you have to collect, you will find some 'KEY Values' for that

Comment: The only problem with this is that it doesn't support any concept of indexing. As data volumes grow, queries will get slower.

Comment: Sorry copying this from my other comment, as they are same: my first table will contain my 1000 file(names), I will have 1000 variables in second table, and nearly 1 million rows to store all the values, link them to variables and filenames. Is that correct? If so, this means I will store everything as text(or one type) or have more than one column for value. This will make it hard to order them. Say, I want to get x attribute, then order them from highest. Is EAV better for this than having 1000 columns?

Comment: @user3002686: you did not give much Information of your data, your questsion sounds a bit like 'how to put the whole world in a database'

Comment: @NateNoonen: I dont understand you comment, as owner of tables i can put an index on them, or what did you mean?

Comment: He said that data types are spread across "integers, bools, text, everything."  File_data's schema contains an ATTR_VALUE (single column).  A query to pull back all data or data of type is fine.  Any query that needs to filter by the data in that column will not perform well.  The only way to do this in an indexable way would be to have a column per datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a different kind of database for what you're doing.  Consider a document database, such as MongoDB, or one of the other not-only-SQL database flavors that allows for manipulation of data in different ways than a traditional table structure.

I just saw the note mentioning that you're only reading as well.  I've had good luck with Solr on a similar dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  This is pretty common

Comment: I believe I understood EAV, http://oi55.tinypic.com/14lho28.jpg looking at here, my first table will contain my 1000 file(names), I will have 1000 variables in second table, and nearly 1 million rows to store all the values, link them to variables and filenames. Is that correct? If so, this means I will store everything as text(or one type) or have more than one column for value. This will make it hard to order them. Say, I want to get x attribute, then order them from highest. Is EAV better for this than having 1000 columns?

Comment: @user3002686: 1000 rows * 1000 cols are always 1e6 'field', even if only the half or less of 1000 cols per row are filled. 1000 rows * (lets say) 300 rows, no i dont want to calculate ;-)

Comment: @user3002686: second point: if you get (and you will like get) new 'fields' you need to update your database structure.

Answer (score -1):

For storage, XML is probably the best way to go.  There is really good support for XML in SQL.
For queries, if they are direct SQL queries, 1000+ rows isn't a lot and XML will be plenty fast.  If you're moving towards a million+ rows, you're probably going to want to take the data that is most selective out of the XML and index that separately.

Link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx