# Dynamic number of columns exceeds max column limitation SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I have what I consider a real need to create a query with several hundred columns.

We are working on a mailing for our client.  In this mailing, they are listing out several locations where their customers can go to get information.  As our designers create the template for this mailing, they are setting up "Slots" for each address.  The number of slots on the mailing varies from one mailing to the other, from 6 to possibly 50.

My need for the query is to setup the merge of data into the mailing.  I need to provide a query where each mailing is 1 record containing all the information they need for that mailing.  I am dynamically creating the SQL statement with the max number of slots on that mailing.  With up to 50 slots on that mailing, my query needs to look like this:

```
MailingID, 
LogoLocation, 
APNCode, 
TFN, 
CopyVersion, 
Slot1_Name, 
Slot1_Address, 
Slot1_City, 
Slot1_State,
Slot1_DateTime,
...
Slot50_Name,
Slot50_Address,
Slot50_City,
Slot50_State,
Slot50_DateTime
```

My first attempt was to create a table with all these fields, but I got this error:

```
The table has been created, but its maximum row size exceeds the allowed maximum of 8060 bytes. INSERT or UPDATE to this table will fail if the resulting row exceeds the size limit.
```

They only want the data in a CSV file, so I don't need to create a temp table for it.

My problem is that I'm trying to create a standard process and with the number of fields varying like that, I want to set this up in a way that we won't blow up the system every time we try and run it.

I've looked at a few pages and found details on the size limitations of SQL Server and several comments saying a table like this shows a bad database design.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.105).aspx
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fec1efbb-94ff-4fe9-8d69-12e95c48587d/its-maximum-row-size-exceeds-the-allowed-maximum-of-8060-bytes-insert-or-update-to-this-table-will?forum=transactsql
[Work around SQL Server maximum columns limit 1024 and 8kb record size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070932/work-around-sql-server-maximum-columns-limit-1024-and-8kb-record-size)

I'm hoping that someone out there has some experience doing this and can share some insights on how to make this efficient.  Is there another way to accomplish this that I don't know about?

UPDATE:
Thanks for all the quick replies.

More detail on my scenario.  You get a flyer in the mail and when you turn the flyer over, it lists 50 locations in your county where you could go take a class or attend a meeting or something.  All the details for that flyer needs to be in 1 record so they can map the fields on the one page. If that county has 50 address/date/time combinations, they need them included in the 1 record so they can properly slot the flyer.  Think giant mail merge where there might only be 100 counties (100 flyers) but each flyer has tons of information.

When the data is actually stored in the database, I'm storing an id for the specific flyer (MailingID) and each address/date/time combo is its own record.  It's just the file they need to merge the details onto the creative piece that has to be denormalized like this.

I haven't been able to find any details on limitations on views.  Does a View have the same limitations as a table?  Would it work to create a view for them that they can download when they need the data?

Comment: What you are doing should be ok as long as you don't fill every column all of the way. Basically, unless you have large values in every column on a single row there will not be an issue.

Comment: Obviously you've got different addresses in each slot, but why do you have 50 of them?  Why are they repeated, as opposed to being new rows?  It _is_ best to avoid this design when possible, although there are valid use-cases (not to the point where you'd have **50** repeats, usually...).  Let's see: `50 * (30 [address] + 15 [city] + 2 [state] + 20 [datetime]) = 3350` (reasonable average lengths) -  Names are under 100 characters long, right?  You should probably be fine, just have robust error checking.

Comment: I agree with the comments you've been seeing about the table structure being bad design.  Can your client accept a CSV file in a more normalized layout?

Answer (score 0):

`All the details for that flyer needs to be in 1 record so they can map the fields on the one page` That is a questionable assumption. Why can't the data be stored in 50 rows in a 2nd table?

Anyway, if you insist on storing everything in one row you should probable use XML or JSON. That makes all these problems go away. SQL Server has great support for XML. You can even generate XML on the fly. So you could properly store the 50 items in a 2nd table and only combine them into one XML value for query purposes.