# SQL Error (1118):Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs

Tags: mysql

I have create one MySQL database table. I have to create 195 columns in one table. I have to give the data types of 190 columns is VARCHAR and 5 columns data type are text. Each columns have length 500.

Actually I want to create 1000 columns in one database table and I want to use data type is VARCHAR in each table columns. Now when I am creating new columns in database table. I am getting this error:

> SQL Error (1118):Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Comment: !95 columns of VARCHAR(500) looks like bad database design. [See](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html) for maximum column details

Comment: I am creating large database first time for web application.I need to create 1000  columns in one database table  with same datatype VARCHAR and length.Can i create 1000 columns in one database table? what i will should do now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Work around SQL Server maximum columns limit 1024 and 8kb record size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070932/work-around-sql-server-maximum-columns-limit-1024-and-8kb-record-size)

Answer (score 6):

You database design is flawed.

Maximum row size with MySQL = 65,535 bytes.

Assuming 1 byte per character 500 X 1000 = 50,000 bytes per row which is approaching 65,535.

For VARCHAR(L) using latin1 1 byte per column is required to hold length L so now we are at 501,000.

For a VARCHAR column that stores multibyte characters, the effective maximum number of characters is less. For example, utf8 characters can require up to three bytes per character.

500 X 4 X 1000 = 2,000,000 bytes (3 per char + 1 for length)

For more information MySQL Documentation [**MySQL Maximum Number of Columns**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/column-count-limit.html) AND [**Data Type Storage Requirements**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html).

I suggest you learn more about database design before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks david strachan

Comment: I disagree with your premise that "your database design is flawed" -- I'd argue MySQL's data storage model is flawed.

Answer (score 3):

Run SQL query/queries on database

```sql
SET GLOBAL innodb_strict_mode=OFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change  the data type from `VARCHAR` to `TEXT` which will overcome the row limitation in `MySQL`.

The query below creates an error due to row limitation:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (a VARCHAR(10000), b VARCHAR(10000),
       c VARCHAR(10000), d VARCHAR(10000), e VARCHAR(10000),
       f VARCHAR(10000), g VARCHAR(6000)) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1;

ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used
table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead,
check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

But when you change it to `TEXT` datatype it works. In the following `MyISAM` example, changing a column to `TEXT` avoids the `65,535-byte` row size limit and permits the operation to succeed because `BLOB` and `TEXT` columns only contribute 9 to 12 bytes toward the row size.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (a VARCHAR(10000), b VARCHAR(10000),
       c VARCHAR(10000), d VARCHAR(10000), e VARCHAR(10000),
       f VARCHAR(10000), g TEXT(6000)) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

[Further reading](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

Comment: The question I am asking myself is: "Why would I use VARCHAR at all and and not always use TEXT?" Using a hardcoded length limitation for Strings sounds pretty much FORTRAN77-style to me. IMHO a robust database design is capable of dealing with user-input that the designer hasn't foreseen... and won't waste space for shorter strings? The only reason i can think of such antique techniques is performance. Is it? And if yes: How big may the impact on perfomance be?

Comment: @ChrisMercator - One reason to use VARCHAR or other data types would be for indexing the columns for searching and joining on that data.  According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203710/which-datatype-is-better-to-use-text-or-varchar, VARCHAR is up to 3 times faster for searching than TEXT.