# How can I store records with 500 CLOB fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Oracle has a max column limit of 1000 and even with all columns defined as VARCHAR(4000) I was able to create the table and load huge amounts of data in all fields.
I was able to create a table in SQL Server with 500 varchar(max) columns, however when I attempt to insert data, I got the following error:

> Cannot create a row of size 13075 which is greater than the allowable
>   maximum row size of 8060.

When I made the table 200 columns I was able to insert huge amounts of data.

Is there a way to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: It probably depends *how* you tried to create said table with 500 fields. SQL Server supports a larger number of columns. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14070932.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `varchar(max)` . . . the maximum length is 4,000.  Hence, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: sorry, it was varchar(4000) for oracle and varchar(max) for sql server.

Comment: @stakx I tried to create 500 varchar(max) fields

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the use case for a thousand column table?

Comment: Use `varchar(max)` for SQL Server.  This should work, because the column data should be stored on other data pages.

Comment: @Luke101: you said that already (*what* you tried to do), but you didn't mention any specifics (*how* you tried to do it).

Comment: Why are you using varchar(max) when for Oracle you used varchar2(4000)?

Comment: What error did you get on INSERT?

Comment: I doubt it you have any justification for this table structure. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I have alot of csv files to import into the database. Its statistical data

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I updated the question with the error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff even if the actual content is stored off row the pointers to it still need to be stored in row and the OP won't be able to get anywhere near 1,000 http://stackoverflow.com/a/14072421/73226

Comment: If it is statistical data why are you storing it as varchar?

Comment: If you are importing with BCP, I'd make a `BCP IN` import to several tables instead of just one to bypass the limitations. You can make several (XML) format files to map the range of columns you need for the different tables. Just an idea, my 2c.

Comment: I meant several `BCP IN` imports with a (XML) format file for each mapping a range of columns in the CSV to a table.

Comment: There's no good reason why "a lot of csv files" should require 1000 CLOB columns.  I strongly recommend that you use a relational design instead.  As an added benefit, you won't run into problems like this.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes everything is varchar(max) then in the select query it will get converted to its proper type

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes I explored using relational design techniques but this will actually complicate things. If everything is in a single table separated by the csv id then it will be very easy to manage. I have hundreds of csv files and it will become a nightmare if I create hundreds of tables. I also explored EAV techniques as well but this will hurt perfomance and mangle the select query.

Comment: "hundreds of tables" isn't relational either.  You need to abstract the source file and the columns, it's that simple.  I have done this many times before and that always ends up being the answer for this kind of thing having thousands of CLOBs in a single row isn't going to do your performance any good, even if it were possible, which it isn't.

Comment: @RBarryYoung can you point to a web page that gives an example of this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran some test and it seems we have an overhead of 26 bytes on each populated varchar(max) column.
I was able to populate 308 columns.
If you'll divide your columns between 2 tables you'll be fine (until the next limitation - which will come).

P.s.
I seriously doubt the justification for this table structure.
Any reason not saving the data as rows instead of columns?